# Как решить проблему JavaScript + TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Всем привет. Как устранить ошибку?

Получаю все элементы

```
 const items = document.querySelectorAll('.tabItem')
```

При такой записи

```
if (items[index]) items[index].style.display = 'none'
```

ругается на

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `querySelectorAll` возвращает тип `NodeListOf<Element>`, в типе `Element` нет свойства `style`. Поэтому надо явно указать, что мы хотим работать с типом `HTMLElement`, у которого указанное свойство имеется.

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.tabItem');

for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    if (items[index]) {
        (items[index] as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```